# jQuery Knockout run computed for each item in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a `ko.computed` function which determines if a current item from a `ko.observableArray()` is valid.

However, the computed function doesn't gets executed for each item in the array

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79nuW/1/)

JavaScript:

```
var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray(["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"]),
};
viewModel.isValid = ko.computed(function() {
    // doesn't gets executed for each item
    console.log(this);

    return true;
}, viewModel);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Html:

```
<script type="text/html" id="item-template">
    <span data-bind="css: { 'valid': $root.isValid }, text: $data"></span>
</script>

<!-- ko template: { foreach: items, name: 'item-template' } --><!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ko.computed` does not automatically walks through all your items. You need to do this yourself:

```
viewModel.isValid = ko.computed(function() {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.items(), function(item) {
        console.log(item);
    });
    return true;
}, viewModel);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49uSE/).

The `ko.computed` only provides you the functionality that it recalculates its value if one of its dependent observable changes.